# Why would the auth0 redux example in the docs throw a null error in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm following the auth0 redux example and following their guide to implement lock.

https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/

This doesn't work throwing an error in the Auth0Lock constructor saying null values are being passed in

```
// ./actions/login.js

const auth0ClientId = 'foo';
const auth0Domain = 'bar.auth0.com';
const lock = new Auth0Lock(auth0ClientId, auth0Domain); // this constructor throws an error saying null values are being passed in
```

Why are the constants being evaluated as null by the Auth0 Lock constructor?

Comment: Hard to believe...feels like there's something missing from this picture

Comment: I've seen very similar behavior when I had circular reference/import. Can you try to remove all imports of local modules from actions.js and see if you still have the same issue?

Comment: it only has 2 imports in actions, Auth0Lock and AsyncStorage - there are no local imports

Comment: ok figured out the issue - the auth0 constructor has changed from their example docs - so it expects a single object rather than separate arguments.  Thus - when i moved it to inside the function - it never errors because a different bug was keeping the function from firing that step.

Comment: So you never actually made sure they were called huh?

Comment: I thought it was being called but was obscured by a different error that was popping up, yeah was a silly mistake.

Comment: Great! I've also taken off the RequireJS tag since it is not a factor in the problem or the solution.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was not with the constant at all.

It turns out that the auth0 constructor has changed from their example docs - so it expects a single config object rather than separate arguments.

Separately, when i moved it to inside the function, it didn't error in the constructor because a different bug was keeping the function from firing that step.

All I needed to do was change the constructor call to this:

`const lock = new Auth0Lock({ clientId, domain });`